# Mass transportation proof of the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality?

Tags: optimal-transportation, isoperimetric-problems

In his book "Topics in optimal transportation", Graduate Studies in Mathematics 58, AMS 2003,
Villani presents a proof, due to Gromov, of the classical isoperimetric inequality
in Euclidean space using mass transportation methods. Is there a (similar)
mass transportation proof towards
the isoperimetric inequality for Gaussian measures?

Comment: It may be useful to look at the paper of Cordero-Erausquin (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002050100185) and at the references contained therein, though I do not believe that this paper proves the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality itself (discussed a bit in Section 3).

Comment: I can't remember the details now, but I have it in my head that there is a transport proof of the Brunn-Minkowski inequality, and (much more hazily) that one can derive the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality from BM (or maybe Prekopa-Leindler),  and so conceivably one can stitch these two observations together. I'll post again if I remember any of the relevant details.

Answer (score 5):

See e.g. Section 2.1 "Talagrand's transport inequalities and Gaussian dimension-free concentration" of [Gozlan's survey](https://www.esaim-proc.org/articles/proc/pdf/2015/04/proc145101.pdf).

Theorem 2.3 there is Talagrand's result that the standard Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^d$ satisfies Talagrand’s transport inequality $\mathbf T_2(2)$. On the other hand, Theorem 2.4 in that survey, with a very short proof, states that, for any real $C>0$, the $\mathbf T_2(C)$ property of a probability measure implies a concentration property for that measure.

It is also well known that a concentration property can be derived from an isoperimetric inequality.

---

On the other hand, the following is stated on p. 669 of [this 2017 AoP paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-45/issue-2/Sharp-dimension-free-quantitative-estimates-for-the-Gaussian-isoperimetric-inequality/10.1214/15-AOP1072.pdf) (with a reference to Villani, C., 2009, Optimal Transport. Old and New):

> it is not known if the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality itself
> can be retrieved from optimal transport

So, if there is a derivation of the Gaussian isoperimetric inequality from optimal transport, it is likely a rather recent one.

Comment: Thank you, but concentration properties are only consequences of the isoperimetric statement, that is usually a more delicate issue with in particular identification of the extremal sets.

Comment: @XiazhongZhu : I have added a remark on this, with further references.